# selecting multiple random images through Flickr Api, Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, flickr

I want to show 4 random (and different) pics from a flickr user's most recent 200 pics. The code has 3 parts

1. Json request to Flickr [works]
2. Javascript random number generator [almost works]
3. Parsing of the Json [works]

I've made a request for 200 pics from flickr and I get a Json return which I save in a variable myArray. I run a function on this var that generates a random number (0-200). Using splice, I save the item that corresponds with the random number in a new variable, selArray. This also removes the item from myArray, preventing it from getting randomly selected again. This function runs x times, x being the amount of random numbers you want. This function doesn't quite do what I want it to do. The last part of the code parses the Json. The last part itself works when I use it on myArray but doesn't work on selArray.

This is the problem. After the function getRandoms is finished, selArray contains 4 arrays each holding an object instead of simply holding 4 objects.
This is what console shows:

```
0 [Object { id="...}]
```

but I want this: (this is what myArray shows)

```
0 Object { id="...}
```

So, here's my question: how do I fix this? What am I doing wrong?
Remark: I was able to make this code work by replacing item with item[0] in the $.each part of the code.

A second question. Is this good code? I'm specifically interested in performance, speed.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var apikey = '[set api here]';
    var userid = '[set id here]';

    $.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.people.getPublicPhotos&api_key='+apikey+'&user_id='+userid+'&per_page=200&format=json&jsoncallback=?',
        function(data){

        // flickr request ok
        if(data.stat == 'ok'){

            var myArray = data.photos.photo;
            var selArray = new Array;

            function getRandoms(number){
                for(var i=0; i < number; i++){
                    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length);
                    selArray.push(myArray.splice(randomNumber,1));
                }
            }

            // get random numbers 
            getRandoms(4);

            //look at selArray in console
            console.dir(selArray);

            //parse json, this works
            $.each(selArray, function(i,item){
                var purl = 'http://farm' + item.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + item.server + '/' + item.id + '_' + item.secret + '_s.jpg';
                var container = '<a target="_blank" href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/'+userid+'/'+item.id+'/"><img class="span4" alt="'+item.title+'" src="' + purl + '"/>';
                $(container).appendTo('#images');
            });

        // flickr request problem
        }else{
            console.log(" The request to get the array was not good ");
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what you want is the following:

```
selArray.push(myArray[randomNumber]);
```

Comment: Oh, that was simple. Yes, this did solve it. I did add this line after: `myArray.splice(randomNumber,1);` To ensure no value from myArray gets randomly selected twice. Thanks!

Comment: Please click the check mark next to the answer if it helped. This allows future visitors to be helped.